# How to use JPA Criteria API in JOIN

Tags: jpa, join

- I have five tables: Company, Product/Service, Address, Country and
  City.
- A Company can have n products with category, 1 address with 1 country
  and 1 city inside the address entity.
- A user has chosen "England - Leeds".
- I know now that I have to select every companies from db where city
  is Leeds and populate product/service-list with those companies'
  products or services. After that user can select for instance dentist
  from the third list.
- After that I know Enlgand - Leeds - Dentist and I have to populate
  the last list with compenies (dentists in Leeds)

---

```
public class Company implements java.io.Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Short companyId;
@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
private Address address;
private String companyName;
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "company",cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
private Set<Product> products = new HashSet<Product>(0);
```

---

```
public class Product implements java.io.Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "productId", unique = true, nullable = false)
private Integer productId;
private Short branchId;
private String productName;
private String sku;
private String category; ------> I am using this field in company search (dentists, garages etc.)
```

How can I query only those companies which have products with category dentist?

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();

CriteriaQuery<Company> criteria = criteriaBuilder.createQuery( Company.class );
Root<Company> companyRoot = criteria.from( Company.class );
//criteria.select(companyRoot);

TypedQuery<Company> q = em.createQuery(criteria);
List<Company> results = q.getResultList();
```

Now I've got every company, how can I select only the companies with the correct category? I think I will need `JOIN` but how I don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 24):

use join(),

```
criteriaBuilder.equal(companyRoot.join("products").get("category"), "dentist")
```

See,
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Querying#Joining.2C_querying_on_a_OneToMany_relationship